# random error "cannot connect to itunes store" in app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have implemented in app purchase in my iPhone application.

But first time while buying product during payment transaction phase I get an error:
`cannot connect to iTunes store` and it results in unsuccessful payment transaction.

Main thing is that it is occurring randomly means in subsequent attempts transaction gets completed successfully and again after 2 or 3 transactions it gives me the same error.

Weird behaviour?

I have tried all online available solutions like resetting, "Log out" from iTune account and creating new test user account but none is working.

I am trying to solve this problem since last three days(was waiting if problem is from iTune server) but no luck at all.

Before this I have successfully submitted no. of apps having in app purchase. Facing this issue first time.

Please do suggest some solution.
Thanks

Comment: Not a solution, but this has been a problem for a while now - Apple's sandbox servers tend to be incredibly unreliable, and iAP's usually never work during development. Also, double check your app permissions to ensure iAP is enabled for your app ID.

Comment: @AlexBlundell its already enabled.

Comment: This is off the top of my head, but try signing out from the App Store on your device, and then try the in-app purchase again with a _test_ account (you can create these in iTunes Connect)

Comment: @AlexBlundell's suggestion worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the error was because of "TimeOutInterval:".

In my In app purchase implementation workflow, in between there was a call to our local server to make entry of subscription in database.

Later I found, because of slow server I was getting late response from server resulting into "requestTimeout".

To solve this problem I increased the timeoutInterval while making request to server. And It worked for me.